# cv::imread() produces empty images for OpenCV 4.0.0 Raspberry Pi 3 (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have just installed OpenCV 4.0.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3. The python library seems to work just fine, however I am unable to get imread() (and other parts of the library such as FileStorage) to work for C++.

I have produced the simple program below to demonstrate the issue:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "start" << endl;

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("~/opencv_test/img.jpg", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    cout << img.cols << img.rows << endl;

    cv::imwrite("./imgoutput.jpg", img);

    cout << "written" << endl;
}
```

The output is as follows:

> start
>
> 00
>
> written

which suggests the image is not being read properly, as the output dimensions are (0,0). The image is valid and present at the specified path. I have tried both .png and .jpg images which all display correctly using the python library. The output image is also written in this example, but is an empty file (as would be expected if the cv::Mat has 0,0 dimensions).

I am compiling with:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I /usr/local/include/opencv4/ test.cpp -o test.o `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`
```

The output for pkg-config is as follows:

> -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core

This seems to contain all of the libs that I would need for this sample.

Again, if I use python to perform the same task it works perfectly fine. Am I compiling incorrectly for C++?

Comment: Use the full path on the filename rather than a tilde (`~`), e.g. `/Users/fred/opencv_test/img.jpg`

Comment: This works - thanks!

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project! The tilde didn't work because the shell normally expands that for you, but you aren't using a shell when you call `cv::imread()`